# Registering Partial Open Generics with Autofac

Tags: generics, autofac

I have the below situation where the class implementing my interface takes multiple generics but only uses one of them in its implementation of the interface (the other is closed) ....

```
public interface ITest<T, TU>
{                   
}

public class Test<T, TU> : ITest<Guid, T>
{
}
```

I have tried registering this as

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Test<,>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

and

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Test<,>)).As(typeof (ITest<,>));
```

but when I try to resolve as

```
container.Resolve<ITest<Guid, string>>();
```

I get

> The requested service 'ITest`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a
>   component to provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

I guess its assuming that generics are of the same type in the implementation and interface? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It is open source, so you can take a look at the generic resolution code: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/OpenGenerics/OpenGenericServiceBinder.cs

Comment: Does your `Test<T, TU>` need its second generic argument? Because if you have it like this `public class Test<T> : ITest<Guid, T>` then the registration `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Test<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();` working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need both generic arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the generic parameter `TU` in the `Test<T, TU>`. Please understand that this `TU` has nothing to do with the `TU` parameter that is defined in `ITest<TU, T>`, but this is a totally different parameter. To make this more obvious, you should rename that parameter, for instance:

```cs
public class Test<T, X> : ITest<Guid, T>
{
}
```

Because this generic parameter is different and does not map to a generic argument in the `ITest<TU, T>` abstraction, Autofac is unable to infer `X` from a requested closed version of `ITest<TU, T>`. Ask yourself: what should `X` be if I request an `ITest<Guid, string>`. This would resolve to `Test<string, X>` but that `X` is still unknown.

Because Autofac can't infer `X`, it will never be able to use `Test<T, X>` and the request will fail.

Since `Test<T, X>` can never be resolved, it is unfortunate that Autofac didn't throw an exception during the call to `RegisterGeneric`, since it should be able to find out that `Test<T, X>` will never be resolved.

So the real question is, what do you want `X` to be when `ITest<Guid,  T>` gets resolved? Autofac does not allow partial generic type definitions, but neither does the C# compiler, so this is generally not a problem. The easiest way to 'fill in' that `X` argument is by deriving from `Test<T, X>`:

```cs
// Part of your Composition Root
internal class FloatTest<T> : Test<T, float>
{
}
```

This class can be registered without a problem:

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FloatTest<>))
    .As(typeof(ITest<,>))
```

Comment: That makes sense when taking a step back and looking at the problem. Thanks.